# Div does not overlap image

Tags: html, css, css-transitions, overlay

I'm struggling here with the fact that my div does not overlap de image. When you hover this div (with a opacity of 0) it gets the opacity of 1 after a transition.

The problem is, though, that the div is below the image, while it should be covering the image (hover somewhere below the image to see the problem) ([JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/MZein/b0r25gbd/2/)):

```css
.column {
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  position: relative;
}

.overlay {
  background: #ddd;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
}

.overlay {
    opacity: 0;       
    transition: opacity .25s linear; /* vendorless fallback */
    -o-transition: opacity .25s linear; /* opera */
    -ms-transition: opacity .25s linear; /* IE 10 */
    -moz-transition: opacity .25s linear; /* Firefox */
    -webkit-transition: opacity .25s linear; /*safari and chrome */
}

.overlay:hover {
    opacity: .75;
}
```

```html
<div class="column">
  <img src="http://cdn.welingelichtekringen.nl/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/hond-584x340.jpg">
  <div class="overlay">
    <p>
      I'm some test text!
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Can anybody help me to make sure the overlay covers the image?

Comment: I thought your question had two parts - (a) the position and (b) cover the image. Is that correct and are you looking for a solution for part b? If yes, I can post an answer. Not sure as you've already accepted one.

Comment: @Harry I need that (b) answer of yours, because that image should have some padding as well, but when I give the overlay the properties ``width: 100%; height: 100%; it goes over the padding of the images, what shouldn't be the case..

Comment: Ok, what are the browsers that you need to support? There is a property to get the image to fit the container without having the aspect ratio affected but it is not supported very widely.

Comment: @Harry if possible all browsers.. But if that isn't possible then it would like to focus on Firefox, Chrome and if possible IE

Comment: IE (as always) is the problem. [This](https://jsfiddle.net/z4fmaooe/) would work in all browsers except IE, will retain your original 300 x 300 dimensions and preserve the aspect ratio of the image.

Comment: Can we have a chat?

Comment: Yes, you can find me [in this room](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69317/svg-css-shapes-and-designs) but I'll be available only for a little more time.

Answer (score 3):

Modify the css overlay class as:

```
.overlay {
 background: #ddd;
 position: absolute;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 opacity: 0;
 left:0;
 top:0; 
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/djsreeraj/b0r25gbd/3/

Answer (score 1):

You have to set the `position:absolute` with the properties `top:0` and `left:0`. You can use the following solution:

```css
.column {
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  position: relative;
}
.overlay {
  background: #ddd;
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
}
.overlay {
  opacity: 0;       
  transition: opacity .25s linear; /* vendorless fallback */
  -o-transition: opacity .25s linear; /* opera */
  -ms-transition: opacity .25s linear; /* IE 10 */
  -moz-transition: opacity .25s linear; /* Firefox */
  -webkit-transition: opacity .25s linear; /*safari and chrome */
}
.overlay:hover {
  opacity: .75;
}
```

```html
<div class="column">
  <img src="http://cdn.welingelichtekringen.nl/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/hond-584x340.jpg">
  <div class="overlay">
    <p>I'm some test text!</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the position: absolute method as mentioned above. Also, if you want to change the size of the image accordingly so it scales down fine, use the `max-width` properties. For example:

```css
.column {
  max-height: 300px;
  max-width: 300px;
  position: relative;
}

.column img {
 max-height: 300px;
 max-width: 100%;
}

.overlay {
  background: #ddd;
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.overlay {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
    opacity: 0;       
    transition: opacity .25s linear; /* vendorless fallback */
    -o-transition: opacity .25s linear; /* opera */
    -ms-transition: opacity .25s linear; /* IE 10 */
    -moz-transition: opacity .25s linear; /* Firefox */
    -webkit-transition: opacity .25s linear; /*safari and chrome */
}

.overlay:hover {
    opacity: .75;
}
```

```html
<div class="column">
  <img src="http://cdn.welingelichtekringen.nl/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/hond-584x340.jpg">
  <div class="overlay">
    <p>
      I'm some test text!
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

While parts of your question has been already answered by others (and correctly), I feel they lack the explanation that is required and some of them also address the question only in part.

Firstly, coming to the reason why the overlay was originally positioned below the element and not over the image (despite it having `position: absolute`) is the following:

- The element has a `width` and a `height` assigned to it but  `left`/`right` or `top`/`bottom` is not specified. When no value is specified for these, the default value (which is `auto`) is set for them. Then the UA resolves the `auto` to the actual values during rendering.
- As per the  the [Visual Rendering Specs by W3C](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#abs-non-replaced-height) when `height` is not `auto` (here it is `100%`) but the `top` and `bottom` are `auto`, then the `top` is set to the static position. Static position means the position of the element on the page when it doesn't have any `position` value set. Here, the element is a `div` and so it would by default get positioned below the `img` (next line). This is why we see it below the image and not on top of it.

  > 'top' and 'bottom' are 'auto' and 'height' is not 'auto', ***then set 'top' to the static position***, set 'auto' values for 'margin-top' and 'margin-bottom' to 0, and solve for 'bottom'
- Similar logic applies for the `left`, `right` and `width` also.

When we give `top: 0px;` and `left: 0px`, we are explicitly instructing the UA to position the element at top-left corner of the parent element and so it now overlays the image properly.

Secondly, even if we do this, we would see that the overlay doesn't actually cover the image because though the container is 300px x 300px, the image's dimensions are not restricted and so it will display the full image whereas the overlay element is 100% x 100% of parent (and so is only 300ps x 300px).

There are three ways to address this. One is to use `max-height` and/or `max-width` method detailed in one of the existing answers but the drawback is that it will scale down the image while preserving it aspect ratio (and so wouldn't be 300px x 300px). The second option is to explicitly set `img` dimension as 300px x 300px (same as parent) but this would resize the image without preserving aspect ratio.

The third option (which I recommend is) to use the `object-fit: cover` on the `img`. Using this would make the image scaled in such a way that its aspect ratio is preserved  and also be the same size as the parent (the extra portions on the bottom and right would be clipped). The only ***drawback*** of using this approach is that it lacks IE support. In IE the image would still display but the aspect ratio won't be maintained.

```css
.column {
  position: relative;
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
}
img {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}
.overlay {
  background: #ddd;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
}
.overlay {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity .25s linear;  /* vendorless fallback */
  -o-transition: opacity .25s linear;  /* opera */
  -ms-transition: opacity .25s linear;  /* IE 10 */
  -moz-transition: opacity .25s linear;  /* Firefox */
  -webkit-transition: opacity .25s linear;  /*safari and chrome */
}
.overlay:hover {
  opacity: .75;
}
```

```html
<div class="column">
  <img src="http://cdn.welingelichtekringen.nl/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/hond-584x340.jpg">
  <div class="overlay">
    <p>
      I'm some test text!
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

The below part is strictly not related to the original question. It was a follow up that we had discussed in chat but I'm adding it here for the sake of continuity.

If the container element has `padding` or `margin` like [here](https://jsfiddle.net/MZein/kau7L5jx/1/) then the overlay would still not be exactly covering the `img`. This is because [`object-fit:cover` property fills only the content-area of the box](https://jsfiddle.net/MZein/kau7L5jx/1/). So, the image would not be present in the padding area of the container whereas the overlay will be present as it takes 100% of parent's dimensions. Overcoming this is requires a simple trick. Reduce the overlay element's size by an amount equal to the `padding` on both sides and set `left` equal to the `padding-left` like [here](https://jsfiddle.net/kau7L5jx/4/).

Comment: Thank you very much for this great expleanation! I really appreciate it :) It's all clearer in my head now :D

Comment: You're welcome @MZeinstra. Happy that I could help you :)

Answer (score 0):

In `overlay` class, add:

```
top:0;
left:0;
```